# Python - производительность, кто разбирается в документации

Tags: python, производительность

Почему конструкция:

```python
try:
    list.index(value)
    return True
except:
    return False
```

Работает быстрее, чем:

```python
if value in list:
```

Суть вопроса в том, почему `.index` работает быстрее, чем `in`.

`in` перебирает список и выходит на первом совпадении, но `index` теоретически делает то же самое. Только вот тесты показали, что `index` быстрее, если нужно подтвердить или опровергнуть вхождение значения в список.

Comment: А как вы мерили? Вообще если вы регулярно используете `in` для списка и это для вас проблема по производительности, то используйте не список, а множество или словарь для таких проверок, у них сложность `O(1)`, в отличие от `O(n)` у списка.

Comment: @CrazyElf, кст, действительно index немного быстрее, попробовал на этом тесте: https://pastebin.com/xjdyjWkA index завершился за 58 секунд, а `in` за 62

Comment: @gil9red 7% разницы... ну, это разве что теоретический интерес может представлять, но не практический )

Comment: @CrazyElf, у меня интерес и правда теоретический, просто делал цикловые замеры, кто быстрее мне выдаст результат.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел исходники методов и оказывается есть небольшая разница в их реализации, думаю в этом может быть причина

[Реализация index](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f64de53ff01e734d48d1d42195443d7d1646f220/Objects/listobject.c#L2520):

```
static PyObject *
list_index_impl(PyListObject *self, PyObject *value, Py_ssize_t start,
                Py_ssize_t stop)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=ec51b88787e4e481 input=40ec5826303a0eb1]*/
{
    Py_ssize_t i;

    if (start < 0) {
        start += Py_SIZE(self);
        if (start < 0)
            start = 0;
    }
    if (stop < 0) {
        stop += Py_SIZE(self);
        if (stop < 0)
            stop = 0;
    }
    for (i = start; i < stop && i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
        PyObject *obj = self->ob_item[i];
        Py_INCREF(obj);
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(obj, value, Py_EQ);
        Py_DECREF(obj);
        if (cmp > 0)
            return PyLong_FromSsize_t(i);
        else if (cmp < 0)
            return NULL;
    }
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "%R is not in list", value);
    return NULL;
}
```

[Реализация in](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f64de53ff01e734d48d1d42195443d7d1646f220/Objects/listobject.c#L423):

```
static int
list_contains(PyListObject *a, PyObject *el)
{
    PyObject *item;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int cmp;

    for (i = 0, cmp = 0 ; cmp == 0 && i < Py_SIZE(a); ++i) {
        item = PyList_GET_ITEM(a, i);
        Py_INCREF(item);
        cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(item, el, Py_EQ);
        Py_DECREF(item);
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

Comment: А можно для слабо знающих C++ пояснить, в каком месте тут может быть выигрыш у `index` и почему? Или тут ясно только то, что код чуть разный и всё? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, честно, мне не хотелось вникать в это :)

Comment: @CrazyElf я вижу разницу в том, что в первом случае переменная cmp объявлена внутри for, и скорее всего компилятор делает ее регистровой переменной. Во втором случае cmp объявлен вне цикла, и используется в условии выхода из цикла. Возможно компилятор размещает эту переменную в стеке, потому что считает, что ее значение должно сохраняться все время работы цикла (но это не точно). Нужно смотреть что компилятор генерирует на разных настройках оптимизации.

Comment: @insolor, а что делает код на С++, с логической точки зрения, можете пояснить?

Comment: @AlgiZ с логической точки зрения - одно и то же в обоих вариантах: последовательно перебирает элементы списка, пока не встретит элемент, совпадающий с указанным.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо!